# How to close a channel gracefully before ssl handshake in Netty?

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I'm adding a throttling feature in my application, which needs to close a channel before the SSL handshake to mitigate CPU usage when the incoming request rate exceeds the threshold. Now I use Netty `SslHandler` with server mode to do the handshake. My current implementation is adding a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` before the `SslHandler` and rewrite the `channelActive` method:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception { 
    if (!limiter.tryAcquire()) {
        ctx.close();
        return;
    }

    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
    ctx.fireChannelActive();
}
```

In this way the channel can be closed when it becomes active. However, I will receive `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent` with handshake failure. I read the source code of Netty `SslHandler`. It will set handshake failure in `channelInactive` method when the channelInactive event is triggered. So I wonder whether there is a better way to close the channel without firing the handshake failure event, since the handshake process has not started when my throttling close the channel.

Answer (score 0):

You're attacking the problem at the wrong end. The idea is not to close channels that are being accepted too quickly, but to not accept them too quickly, which will be done in the accept handler, not the channel handler.

Comment: Do you mean modify the `ServerSocketChannel`? I have a solution to add an InboundHandler to the `NioServerSocketChannel`, so I can close an incoming channel before it is registered and active. However, that means I have to use `channel.unsafe().closeForcibly()`. If I use the normal `channel.close()` method, Netty throws channel not registered exception. But according to Netty documents [Unsafe](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.Unsafe.html), that seems to be internal API and we should not use it?

Comment: I mean either stop accepting connections or deregister interest in OP_ACCEPT while you have your maximum number of connections, however Netty does that. You don't want to close connections: it is already too late; and you don't need to close the `ServerSocketChannel` either. Essentially just don't call `accept()`.

Comment: I used to consider this solution at the beginning. However, I am adding a rate limiting feature, which means I need to accept some connection requests per second and refuse the remaining ones. If simply let `Netty` not accept new connections, that's not the goal of rate limiting. Of course, I can modify `OP_ACCEPT` every second to control the number of connections `Netty` accepts per second, but is that a good solution?

Comment: So you need to accept so many connections in each second, and then stop accepting them for the rest of that second. That meets your objective exactly. Unclear why you think otherwise,

Comment: I just wonder whether it is a good practice to modify `OP_ACCEPT` in high frequent pattern (modify it two times per second), will it causes high overhead for `Netty`?

Comment: No it isn't, but in any case you don't have to modify it twice a second if this is a concern: do it every two seconds, or five, or ten, whatever you like. You seem to be clutching at straws.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost right, however, it would be correct to override `channelRegistered` method instead of `channelActive`.

```
@Override
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    if (isGlobalLimitReached()) {
        ctx.close();
    } else {
        ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
        ctx.pipeline().addFirst(sslCtx.newHandler(ctx.alloc()));
        ctx.fireChannelRegistered();
    } 
}
```

Also, you need to add `SslHandler` at the beginning of pipeline on the fly and only when your condition is met (no limit reached).

In that case, you'll not get `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent`. As handshake is started when  `SslHandler` is added to pipeline and 
`channel.isActive()` return true (your case in above code).

`channelRegistered` is most recent point where you can refuse/close connection.

Comment: That's what confused me. I use debug mode to try to find out when `SslHandler` start handshaking. It seems that the handler with client mode starts handshaking when the channel is active. If the `SslHandler` is in server mode, it starts handshaking when channel is reading (there is a `readDuringHandshake` flag in `SslHandler` source code). What confused me most is that, even it starts handshaking when channel is active, my handler is added before `SslHandler` and my `channelInactive` method should run before handshaking and close the channel. Why it still gives `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent`?

Comment: Or just like you said, handshake is started when `SslHandler` is added to pipeline, but it seems starts immediately and before the channel becomes active.

Comment: Update: Modify the method to `channelRegistered` and test it, `Netty` still gives `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent`.

Comment: @JianZhu my bad, I didn't look inside channel.isActive() method. Please check my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to add the `SslHandler` to the pipeline dynamically based on the conditions. If the condition matches, I add `SslHandler`, otherwise I don't add it. This solution works well for my use case. Just still wonder why the first solution doesn't work. As I said in the Update comment, I try to add a handler which rewrites `channelRegistered` method like the code in your answer, and add it before the SslHandler. I will still get the `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent`. Does that mean the handshake has begun, even before the `channelResigtered` event is fired?

Comment: @JianZhu look like the problem is that when `SslHandler` in pipeline - `ctx.close()` triggers `channelInactive` method of `SslHandler` where `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent` is created.

Comment: Yeah, I also find that the `channelInactive` triggers the problem using IDE debug mode. However, I'm confused whether the handshake has start or not. If not, why the `SslHandler` sends `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent` with handshake failure when I close the channel?